# Composer package not showing up in autoload_namespaces

Tags: namespaces, composer-php

This should be an easy one.  I developed a package call it MyVendor\MyPackage

inside `MyVendor\MyPackage` is:

- MyVendor\MyPackage\composer.json
- MyVendor\MyPackage\MyClass.php

The `MyVendor\MyPackage\composer.json` file contains:

```
{
    "name":"MyVendor/MyPackage",
    "description":"MyClass!!!",
    "keywords": ["MyKeyword"],
    "homepage": "http://MyPackage.com",
    "type":"library",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "ME",
            "email": "ME@ME.com",
            "homepage":"http://ME.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {

    },
    "autoload":{
        "psr-4" : {
            "MyVendor\\MyPackage\\":""
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have another project called `MyOtherPackage` whose `composer.json` file looks like:

```
{
"require": {
    "monolog/monolog": "1.2.*",
    "MyVendor/MyPackage": "1.0.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "MyVendor\\MyOtherPackage\\": "MyOtherPackage/",
        "MyVendor\\": "/"
    }
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "MyVendor/MyPackage",
            "version": "1.0.0",
            "source": {
                "url": "https://ME.com/svn/MyVendor/MyPackage/",
                "type": "svn",
                "reference": "trunk"
            }
        }
    }
]
}
```

So MyOtherPackage depends on MyPackage.  Everything downloads just fine, but if I open up autload_namespaces.php it only includes monolog.  It looks like this:

```
return array(
    'Monolog' => array($vendorDir . '/monolog/monolog/src'),
);
```

Why isn't `MyVendor/MyPackage` appear in the `namespaces.php` or `autoload_psr4.php` file?  Is the `composer.json` file wrong?

**EDIT** I added to the MyPackage composer.json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out.  It seems as if defining the repository as a package, I am telling composer that it isn't a composer compatible class, which means composer doesn't look for a composer.json file.

To fix it I removed the package definition and made the dependent class's composer.json file to look like:

```
{
    "require": {
         "monolog/monolog": "1.2.*",
         "MyVendor/MyPackage": "1.0.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyVendor\\MyOtherPackage\\": "MyOtherPackage/",
            "MyVendor\\": "/"
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "svn",
            "url": "https://ME.com/svn/MyVendor/MyPackage/",
            "reference": "tags"
        }
    ]
}
```

This tells composer to download the package from this repository and look for the composer.json file.

Answer (score 0):

You did not define any autoload mechanism in your first package. If you don't, Composer cannot know how to autoload the classes, and does nothing (which is a valid option if your package does not contain any PHP at all, but for example only images and javascript).

Add something like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "MyVendor\\Namespace":"src/path"
    }
}
```

Comment: I added `"autoload":{
  "psr-4" : {
   "MyVendor\\MyPackage\\":""
  }
 }` And the package works when I run composer install, but when I include it as a dependency, it still isn't showing up in the namespaces file.  Thanks for the help by the way!

Comment: PSR-4 autoloading is not contained in the `autoload_namespaces.php`, but in `autoload_psr4.php`.

Comment: The `autoload_psr4.php` file similarly, does not have the file in the mapping.  It has the autoload definitions from MyOtherPackage, but not from MyPackage.  The bottom line is when I try to access the webpage I get: `Class 'MyVendor\MyPackage\MyClass' not found in...`

Comment: I wonder if the MyPackage's composer.json file is never being found. Do I have to do something to tell Composer where it is?  Is the repository section set up properly?